# Assigning Vector Values Based on Both Preceding and Following Values

Tags: r

I have a vector/column in a dataframe with dummy variables that looks like this:

2 2 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 2

But I would like to get it to look like this:

2 2 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 4 4 4 4 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 2

Essentially I would like to replace all 0's that are after a 2 and before a 1 with 3's and replace all 0's that are after a 1 but before a 2 with 4's.  How would I go about doing so?

Keep in mind that the number of 0's between the 1's and 2's is not constant. This is also just a small snippet of a large dataframe (>13,300 observations) but currently every value in this vector is either a 0, 1, or 2.

Reproducible input:

```
x = c(2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
2L)
```

Comment: What have you already tried? Is your question a syntax problem or a logic problem? Do you know how you want to do it, your syntax just isn't doing what you want, or do you not know how to do this?

Comment: I've added code for input. Please correct it if it doesn't accurately represent your example.

Comment: Can someone post or comment a regex answer ? I don't know how to replace n 0s with n 3s, I have this : `gsub("20*1","231",paste(v_in,collapse=""))`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper you can use `\`regmatches<-\`` to be able to replace

Comment: I added a regex solution to my answer using `regmatches<-` but I think it's not optimal.

Answer (score 2):

Since you need to process things sequentially, `Reduce` is useful here. For example

```
Reduce(function(a, b) {
  if (b==0) {
    if (a==2) {
      3
    } else if (a==1) {
      4
    } else {
      a
    }
  } else {
    b
  }
}, x, accumulate=TRUE)
# [1] 2 2 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 4 4 4 4 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 1
#[33] 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 2
```

This does assume that the only numbers in the original sequence are 0, 1, or 2 and that the same number never appears on both sides of a string of 0s.

Answer (score 2):

Using `rle` and `inverse.rle` :

```
y <- rle(x)
y$values[y$values == 0] <-  y$values[-1][y$values == 0] +2
inverse.rle(y)
# [1] 2 2 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 4 4 4 4 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 2
```

Using `data.table` and rolling joins:

```
library(data.table)
y <- setkey(data.table(z=x+2)[,id:=1:.N][x!=0],id)
x[x==0] <- y[.(1:max(id)),roll=-Inf][x==0,z]
# [1] 2 2 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 4 4 4 4 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 2
```

Or with `tidyverse`, a bit overkill:

```
x[x==0] <- NA
library(tidyverse)
tibble(x,y=x) %>%
   fill(x,.direction = "up") %>%
   fill(y,.direction = "down") %>%
   mutate(z = case_when(x < y ~3L, x > y ~ 4L, TRUE ~ x)) %>%
   pull(z)

 # [1] 2 2 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 4 4 4 4 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 2
```

Finally, a solution using regex:

```
y <- paste(x,collapse="")
m <- gregexpr("20*1",y)
regmatches(y,m)[[1]] <- chartr("0","3",regmatches(y,m)[[1]])
y <- chartr("0","4",y)
as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(y,"")))

# [1] 2 2 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 4 4 4 4 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 2
```

Comment: why use lead? Why not use `3:4` instead? ie `y=rle(x);
y$values[!y$values]=3:4; inverse.rle(y)`?

Comment: and recycle the value  ? that's clever. A bit less flexible though, we don't know if the sequence will start with 2, and my solution will do OK in case of `...200112200001...` (which might not happen)

Comment: Your first solution is also tidyverse I guess, since lead is not a function in R.

Comment: Edited, thanks, I should start using `reprex` for SO :).